# OV7670 camera, how to use external SPI SRAM?

Tags: arduino, sram

I'm using OV7670 camera with no FIFO and Arduino Mega2560 and I want to send 76800 bytes to my laptop, because of Arduino RAM limitations, I'm planning to use Serial SRAM 23LC1024 (1Mbit) so I can store the bytes for a grey QVGA image and then read them into the Arduino and then to my laptop via serial link. I have tried OV7670 with FIFO(AL422B), didn't work for me.
I don't want to go into too much details about my project, this is all so new to me, just want to see if what I want to do, does even sound possible:

Read 76800 bytes from the pins of the camera output at a frequency of 12MHz ---> send them as they come to parallel to serial shift register ---> Store the data as they come in Serial SRAM ---> Arduino ---> Laptop

or

Read 76800 bytes from camera 8 output pins at 12MHz clock frequency or slower, send all 8 bits from camera to an Arduino port and then read the port 8 bit value ---> send that value to SPI RAM ---> later on send that to laptop via serial link.

Is there a better(or correct) way to write 76800 bytes from camera to the SPI SRAM ?